# I ran "dd if=file1" on accident and gibberish started flowing - Bad?

Tags: dd

I ran "dd if=correctfilelocation" on accident before I was able to add in the second half of the command and gibberish text in terminal started going crazy.

Did I break anything? The file was an OS I was trying to copy to a usb. I didn't type anything after "if=filename".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. All you did was floating your screen with raw content from that image. `of=FILE` operand will tell `dd` to **NOT** write to `stdout`. So as you missed that one, all content ended up in your terminal.

It could be, that your current terminal is messed up because the shell interpreted some of that gibberish text as format instructions. But all you need to do is to close the current terminal window or log out and log in again if you're on pure command line

Comment: Or use the `reset` command.

Comment: @Fernando if this answers your question please consider to accept this as the answer by pressing the grey check-mark.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting but just wanted to check. Phew.